# aspnet_compiler WebSite project

Tags: aspnet-compiler

Can I compile a WebSite project(3.5) using utility aspnet_compiler from command line without installing IIS if I am using local web server for development?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You'll have to specify the virtual path you'll host it on the server though:

```
aspnet_compiler -v /deploymentVirtualPath -p D:\InputWebSite D:\CompiledWebsite
```

This will compile the Web site in "D:\InputWebsite" to "D:\CompiledWebsite" and expects it to get deployed in "/deploymentVirtualPath" virtual path on the production server. If you need to deploy it in the Website root, just specify "/" as the virtual path.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I don't need to deploy it, just compile for debugging purposes, so looks like "/" in -v path should be sufficient?